# Completely delete commits made on Google Code

Tags: eclipse, svn, google-code, mylyn

After working the whole day with Google Code our group of developers was able to evolve a good workflow, however our work for now wasn't that what we expected so i would like to know whether there is an easy possibility to return to "Revision 3" from the current "Revision 27" **and** to delete all releases/commit > 3 without having to create a new project (so that we have a *clean* project). We are working with Eclipse Helios and Mylyn with Subversive SVN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to delete it from the repository, but you will be able to commit a change which will undo all the commits from 4 to 27.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo and my answer in [SVN Revert Trunk, remove a revision as if it never existed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202453/svn-revert-trunk-remove-a-revision-as-if-it-never-existed)